# Android - effectively use a background image in an activity, avoid memory issues

Tags: android, image, image-processing, background, out-of-memory

Is it alright to use at all Background images?

I once had a bad experience using background images because they use a lot of memory when loaded, even causing OOM exceptions in some devices.

I have almost thought that it is a bad practice, as most of the apps have simple backgrounds/effects in Android, compared to their iOS counterparts.

Hence, I only use them on login pages or other pages that are only shown occasionally.

Moreover, whatsapp still uses its fullscreen background, so it makes me think it is maneagable in some way, or probably WA doesn't need much memory.

Or is it enough to simply pass the image to the nodpi drawable folder?

[image]

Comment: Google blogspot article on this: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

I've used images as background on several apps ( some of them commercial )

Generally you can use .png for simple graphics without too many colors.

If you use a .jpg file (photos) you can reduce the quality of the saved image. I usually use "gimp" to do this. You can reduce the quality very substantially without impacting what the user sees. The result is a very small file.

I look forward to better SVG support going down the road...but we are not there yet.

When you are loading them you can use Config.RGB_565 to help reduce your memory footprint.

Comment: Yes but even when you compress the image (lets say 100kb) it is converted to bitmap when placed and then it uses 5 or more MB